Black screen when launching Lightweight Charts on Windows 11
I have been trying to solve this problem for a long time, but so far without success.
I haven't found a solution anywhere.
import pandas as pd
from lightweight_charts import Chart

if __name__ == '__main__':

    chart = Chart()
    df = pd.read_csv('ohlcv.csv')
    chart.set(df)
    chart.show(block=True)


ohlcv.csv file




date
open
high
low
close
volume




0
2010-06-29
1.2667
1.6667
1.1693
1.5927
277519500.0


1
2010-06-30
1.6713
2.028
1.5533
1.5887
253039500.0


2
2010-07-01
1.6627
1.728
1.3513
1.464
121461000.0


3
2010-07-02
1.47
1.55
1.2473
1.28
75871500.0


4
2010-07-06
1.2867
1.3333
1.0553
1.074
101664000.0


5
2010-07-07
1.0933
1.1087
0.9987
1.0533
102645000.0


6
2010-07-08
1.0567
1.1793
1.038
1.164
114526500.0


7
2010-07-09
1.18
1.1933
1.1033
1.16
60061500.0


8
2010-07-12
1.1533
1.2047
1.1233
1.1413
32487000.0



CSV data as text may be needed
,date,open,high,low,close,volume
0,2010-06-29,1.2667,1.6667,1.1693,1.5927,277519500.0
1,2010-06-30,1.6713,2.028,1.5533,1.5887,253039500.0
2,2010-07-01,1.6627,1.728,1.3513,1.464,121461000.0
3,2010-07-02,1.47,1.55,1.2473,1.28,75871500.0
4,2010-07-06,1.2867,1.3333,1.0553,1.074,101664000.0
5,2010-07-07,1.0933,1.1087,0.9987,1.0533,102645000.0
6,2010-07-08,1.0567,1.1793,1.038,1.164,114526500.0
7,2010-07-09,1.18,1.1933,1.1033,1.16,60061500.0
8,2010-07-12,1.1533,1.2047,1.1233,1.1413,32487000.0


pls add what output you expect and what you got?

Output: I would like to see some chart, but there is nothing shown on the screen..

i run you code and works fine .

Answering if this is till an issue.
Try python 3.10.6 or 3.11.9, I had a similar issue and switching versions fixed it.
I had posted it on the repo as a query and got above response. I myself tried py3.11.9 and can see output

I'll try, thank you.
